# how do i install ubuntu without using all harddrive space

Tags: installation

I want to install Ubuntu without using all the space on my hard drive. Where can I learn how to properly manually create the partitions during installation of 12.10?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Windows installer for Ubuntu Desktop (Wubi)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows). It is what you are looking for. Keep installation size about 15 to 20GB.